# Convert inline XML node to nested nodes in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I've an XML file such as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LayoutControl ID="rootlyt" Type="LayoutControl">
  <LayoutGroup ID="lgp8" Header="PersonalInfo" IsCollapsed="False" IsLocked="False" Orientation="Vertical" View="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Height="295" Type="GroupItem" Properties="IsCollapsible=False,IsCollapsed=False,IsLocked=False,">
    <Element ID="layout2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" Height="25" Label="Name" Background="#00FFFFFF" ContentName="txt2" Type="TextEdit" />
  </LayoutGroup>
</LayoutControl>
```

For some reasons , I need to create child and nested nodes from the `Element` node `attributes`.
The output that I want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LayoutControl ID="rootlyt" Type="LayoutControl">
  <LayoutGroup ID="lgp8" Header="PersonalInfo" IsCollapsed="False" IsLocked="False" Orientation="Vertical" View="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Height="295" Type="GroupItem" Properties="IsCollapsible=False,IsCollapsed=False,IsLocked=False,">
    <Element >
      <ID>layout2</ID>
      <HorizontalAlignment>Left</HorizontalAlignment>
      <VerticalAlignment>Top</VerticalAlignment>
      <Width>300</Width>
      <Height>25</Height>
      <Label>Name</Label>
      <Background>#00FFFFFF</Background>
      <ContentName>txt2</ContentName>
      <Type>TextEdit</Type>
    </Element>
  </LayoutGroup>
</LayoutControl>
```

How can i do it?
Or any idea , reference ,article ...

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible way; for each `<Element>`'s attribute add a corresponding child element, and then remove all the attributes afterwards :

```
var raw = @"<LayoutControl ID='rootlyt' Type='LayoutControl'>
  <LayoutGroup ID='lgp8' Header='PersonalInfo' IsCollapsed='False' IsLocked='False' Orientation='Vertical' View='GroupBox' HorizontalAlignment='Left' VerticalAlignment='Top' Width='380' Height='295' Type='GroupItem' Properties='IsCollapsible=False,IsCollapsed=False,IsLocked=False,'>
    <Element ID='layout2' HorizontalAlignment='Left' VerticalAlignment='Top' Width='300' Height='25' Label='Name' Background='#00FFFFFF' ContentName='txt2' Type='TextEdit' />
  </LayoutGroup>
</LayoutControl>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(raw);
foreach(var element in doc.Descendants("Element"))
{
    //add a series of child elements according to existing attributes
    element.Add(
        element.Attributes()
               .Select(attribute => new XElement(attribute.Name.LocalName, attribute.Value))
    );

    //remove the attributes
    element.Attributes().Remove();
}

Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

**<kbd>[`dotnetfiddle demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s2A0Tb)</kbd>**

For more complex transformations of XML, look into XSLT.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an XSL Style Sheet Coded for your exact file. Hopefully this is what you need.

You can use an online [XSL Transfrom tool like this one](http://www.freeformatter.com/xsl-transformer.html) or use a script.

Here is the XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<LayoutControl ID="rootlyt" Type="LayoutControl">
    <LayoutGroup ID="lgp8" Header="PersonalInfo" IsCollapsed="False" IsLocked="False" Orientation="Vertical" View="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Height="295" Type="GroupItem" Properties="IsCollapsible=False,IsCollapsed=False,IsLocked=False,">
      <xsl:for-each select="/LayoutControl/LayoutGroup/Element">
        <Element>
            <ID><xsl:value-of select="@ID"/></ID>
            <HorizontalAlignment><xsl:value-of select="@HorizontalAlignment"/></HorizontalAlignment>
            <VerticalAlignment><xsl:value-of select="@VerticalAlignment"/></VerticalAlignment>
            <Width><xsl:value-of select="@Width"/></Width>
            <Height><xsl:value-of select="@Height"/></Height>
            <Label><xsl:value-of select="@Label"/></Label>
            <Background><xsl:value-of select="@Background"/></Background>
            <ContentName><xsl:value-of select="@ContentName"/></ContentName>
            <Type><xsl:value-of select="@Type"/></Type>
        </Element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </LayoutGroup>
</LayoutControl>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Linq`.

```
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filepath);

    foreach(var element in doc.Descendants("Element")
                              .Select(x=> new {element =x, attributes= x.Attributes()}))
    {
        var attributes = element.attributes.ToList();

        element.element.RemoveAttributes(); // remove all attributes.

        foreach(XAttribute attribute in attributes)         
        {   
            element.element.Add(new XElement(attribute.Name, attribute.Value)); // Convert each attribute to an element
        }
    }
```

**Output**

```
  <LayoutGroup ID="lgp8" Header="PersonalInfo" IsCollapsed="False" IsLocked="False" Orientation="Vertical" View="GroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380" Height="295" Type="GroupItem" Properties="IsCollapsible=False,IsCollapsed=False,IsLocked=False,">
    <Element>
      <ID>layout2</ID>
      <HorizontalAlignment>Left</HorizontalAlignment>
      <VerticalAlignment>Top</VerticalAlignment>
      <Width>300</Width>
      <Height>25</Height>
      <Label>Name</Label>
      <Background>#00FFFFFF</Background>
      <ContentName>txt2</ContentName>
      <Type>TextEdit</Type>
    </Element>
  </LayoutGroup>
</LayoutControl>
```

Fiddle [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3pizf0)

Comment: Your solution is one of the best ways, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Get the xml node first, Then traverse the attributes, convert the attributes to a new node, append to the xml node and remove the attribute, you can do something like this:

```
        XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlstring);

        XmlNode elementNode = xmldoc.SelectSingleNode("LayoutControl/LayoutGroup/Element");

        if (elementNode != null)
        {
            foreach (XmlAttribute attribute in elementNode.Attributes)
            {
                XmlElement elementchild = xmldoc.CreateElement(attribute.Name);
                elementchild.InnerText = attribute.Value;
                elementNode.AppendChild(elementchild);
            }
        }
        elementNode.Attributes.RemoveAll();
```

Hope This can help